# How to estimate total CO2 emission per year due to rocket manufacture?

Tags: rockets, atmosphere, mass, manufacturing, climate

I'm working on a study on greenhouse gas emissions related to rockets. While I have the post-launch (atmospheric) emissions, I need data for emissions related to production. For example, according to this brief by the US International Trade Office:

- [Carbon Border Adjustments: A Catalyst for Lower Aluminum Industry Emissions](https://www.usitc.gov/publications/332/executive_briefings/ebot_primary_aluminum_emissions.pdf) Executive Briefing on Trade, August 2020

about 11 Mt of carbon dioxide is released on average worldwide per every 1 Mt of aluminum smelted (aluminum is the primary component in rocket hulls and parts).

So, in order to total CO2 emission per year due to rocket manufacture I could either use a sum of all the empty weight (empty weight meaning not including propellant) of all the rockets launched worldwide in a range of years from 2000-2019, or I could use just a general sum of rocket emissions per year from 2000-2019, or something along those lines.

Comment: I've made some edits to your question, mostly formatting, but please double check the meaning hasn't been affected. I'm wondering where you'd like to draw the line; just in the production of raw materials, or transportation and running the facility (HVAC, electricity, etc.) where the rockets are built, or the workforce driving back and forth to work, etc.? Carbon footprints are notoriously hard to calculate in a way that everyone agrees with. Just fyi I posted a link to your question in [Sustainability SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: "aluminum is the primary component in rocket hulls and parts": not in rocket engines, a significant component of the overall dry mass of a rocket stack. And solid boosters typically use steel or composite casings. Aside from that...2020 had 114 launches. If each expended 100 t of aluminum or its equivalent (an enormous overestimate), that's about 125 kt of CO2 emissions by your numbers. That'd be <0.0004% of the 34.8 Gt whole. Do you really need more accurate numbers?